# Want to find value which lies within range of array fields

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

```
 {
"_id" : 1,
"password" : "$2a$10$09XFcS7kSOpZBepd/uS8sO/5a7WU2B68L18TrC/EJ2Jjf3zX3mc8C",
"username" : "neetu",
"name" : "neetu12",
"__v" : 3,
"Address" : "America",
"DOB" : ISODate("2000-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"),
"Email" : "neetu@gmail.com",
"isActive" : false,
"joiningDate" : ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
"salary" : "20000",
"profile" : ObjectId("54f02d1538f604c0116752e2"),
"reciptBook" : [ 
    {
        "startingReciptNumber" : 3001,
        "endingReciptNumber" : 3100,
        "_id" : ObjectId("550aa7a5a6d7f2c80f028154")
    }, 
    {
        "startingReciptNumber" : 9000,
        "endingReciptNumber" : 9099,
        "_id" : ObjectId("550bcbb3544cdb60102ac736")
    }
 ]}
```

I have a document like this in user schema . What i want here is to get a the endingReciptNumber from the reciptBook  array in user schema where this recipt Value(which is provide by me) lies.

For this i have written a code in backend:

```
  apiRouter.route('/users/:_id/:reciptValue')
    .get(function(req, res){
    User.find({'_id':req.params._id,'reciptBook.startingReciptNumber':{$gte     : +req.params.reciptValue}}, function(err, obj){
            if(err) res.json(err);
             console.log(obj);
             res.json(obj);
             });
         });
```

Here i am passing id of the logged in user and the recipt value for which the array reciptBook will have that value within the range of startingreciptNumber and endingReciptNumber values. But the api file is not returning anything .Where am I wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misusing the find function. It's far more powerful than you think :p

Actually, find takes only one argument, which is a callback which will be called with three arguments : the element to test, the index of that element, and the array. You will return true if the tested element is valid.
documentation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

So basically, what you want to do is :

```
var myElement = User.find(function(element, index, array){
    return element["_id"] == req.params._id && element.reciptBook.startingReciptNumber == {$gte: +req.params.reciptValue};
})
```

That should return the first matching value in your array, or undefined of the element has not been found.